# Make DGrid selector shown or hidden based on row content

Tags: dojo, grid, selection, selector, dgrid

I'm using the Dgrid Selection grid for a grid that uses check boxes for selecting the content. However, only child node of the tree should show the checkbox as the parents are just categories and can't be selected. Previously I used the editor plugin for this, but it created difficulty with clearing selections (specifically, the "clearSelection" method of the grid did nothing). I switched to the selector plugin, so now selecting and deselecting rows works fine, but now I can't seem to figure out a way to hide the check box on some rows and not others.

**Original code**

```
var columns = [
    editor({
        label: " ",
        field: "itemSelected",
        sortable: false,
        width: 33,
        canEdit: function(object) {
            // only add checkboxes for child objects
            return object.type === "child";
        }
    }, "checkbox"),
    tree({
        label: "Item",
        field: "shortItemId",
        width: 150, 
        shouldExpand: function() {
            return 1;
        }
    }),
    {
        label: "Grouping Name",
        field: "groupingName"
    }
];

var itemGrid = new SelectionGrid({
    store: itemStore,
    style: {
        width: '99%',
        height: '99%'
    },
    columns: columns,
    sort: [{attribute: "shortItemId", descending: false}]
});
```

I used the "editOn" parameter of the editor to hide the check box, but the selector plugin only has the "disabled" parameter, which doesn't hide the field at all.

Is there a way I can get the check box hidden using the selector like I did with the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `dgrid/selector` source, it seems that the input is always created and added to the DOM, regardless of whether it has been disabled. Presumably this is to allow it to be flexible enough to enable and disable checkboxes on the fly without the need to constantly re-create DOM nodes. While it is not possible to prevent these nodes from being rendered, it is possible to hide them with CSS, since the cell node is given a class with the format `field-{fieldName}` (or in this particular case, `field-itemSelected`):

```
// JavaScript
var columns = [
    selector({
        label: " ",
        field: "itemSelected",
        sortable: false,
        width: 33,
        // Disable any checkbox that is not of type "child"
        disabled: function (item) {
            return item.type !== 'child';
        }
    }),
    ...
];

/* CSS */
.field-itemSelected input[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```